# nexus - hosting Nuget and docker images

Tags: docker, nuget, nexus

I am doing some research on the use of Nexus and wanted to know if I need to have 2 separate instances of nexus running for having support for Nuget and docker images.
There is a need to have a repository for Nuget packages as well as docker images as a private repository

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same repository to host both docker and NuGet artifacts. You have to use nexus 3.x though, since nexus 2 doesn't support docker images.